# Erro não capturado: Propriedade 'nativeElement' não pode ser lida

Tags: angular, ionic

Estou implementando uma interface clone do aplicativo do Uber e tentando renderizar um mapa através das API's do Google, porém ao executar o código o mapa não carrega e o console apresenta o seguinte erro:

***core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined***, caso alguém possa ajudar por gentileza.

Detalhe para o OnInit que está importado porém consta como se ele não estivesse sendo usado, tentei achar algo a respeito de sua importação porém não encontrei nada relacionado.

**home page TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Environment, GoogleMap, GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { LoadingController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: any;
  private loading: any;
  private map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapElement = this.mapElement.nativeElement;

    this.mapElement.style.width = this.platform.width() + 'px';
    this.mapElement.style.height = this.platform.height() + 'px';

    this.loadMap();
  }

  async loadMap() {
    this.loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({ message: 'Por favor, aguarde...' });
    await this.loading.present();

    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': 'AIzaSyAAogVAZBAiK6dS3oSp9wgeuoH6M-ffxZg',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': 'AIzaSyAAogVAZBAiK6dS3oSp9wgeuoH6M-ffxZg'
    });

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.mapElement);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No `ngOnInit` o html ainda não foi redenrizado. Tente adicionar esse código no `ngAfterViewInit`.